# scheduling a command to execute right after a *running* command finishes?

Tags: bash

Sometimes I will run a command 'foo', and it takes way longer than I expect it to. If I were to rerun it, I'd probably do something like:

```
foo && mail -s "foo is done" me@com.com
```

..so it emails me when it's done and I can go do something else. But what if I already launched foo and I don't want to restart it? Is there a way to append the && mail... part to the original command, so to speak?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can suspend `foo` with Control-Z, then relaunch it with `fg`. To run `mail` after `foo` is done, suspend and relaunch with `fg && mail -s "foo is done" me@com.com`, which will continue `foo` and execute `mail` when `foo` is done. (Note that because you're using `&&`, `mail` will only execute if `foo` is successful. To run regardless of if it succeeds or fails, use `;` instead of `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

Suspend it with <kbd>ctrl-z</kbd> and then use `bg` to send it to the background and then `wait %1 && <command>` (where `%1` is the number in brackets from running `bg`) or if it is the only backgrounded command then just `wait; <command>` will work (but you can't use `&&` reliably in that case since a bare `wait` always returns zero).